# I want to pass string to oracle procedure but then i want to convert it to comma seperated integer array

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I have string as `st = "19,123,345,567,678";`
but in oracle procedure i want to use condition like 
where id in st

Comment: What is the type of your column you want to put condition?

Comment: Create your SQL statement as string an use 'Excecute Immediate'. Or simply use the like operator ... '19,123,345,567,678' like '%345%'

Comment: So you want to pass the string to an Oracle procedure and then treat it as a list of numbers in Oracle?

Comment: yes sir... i want to use IN  for that string

Comment: please give me solution its urgent... please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn´t read the comments:

yourlist has the value '19,123,345,567,678'

here is the hint

```
',' || yourlist || ',' like '%,345,%'
```

Comment: Column is of varchar2 type

Comment: You marked it as solution, so you found it? You can use this in PL/SQL in your IF statement or in your WHERE clause in a select statement

Comment: So I have no exact understanding of your problem: Exactly WHAT steps do you need?

Comment: Solved. Thanks to all.